# Spring @Autowired does NOT fail even if <context:annotation-config> is missing

Tags: spring

I ran across a peculiar situation. I use SpringJunit4Runner to run some integration tests. I use the `@ContextConfiguration` tag on the test itself.

Lets say I have a class like this

```
public ClassUnderTest {
    @Autowired
    SomeDependency someClass;
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public TestClass {

   @Autowired
   ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

}
```

I want this to failfast if the autowiring fails for `SomeDependency`. Incidentally I forgot to add the line
`<context:annotation-config/>` in my applicationContext.xml. No `<context:component-scan/>`either.
What I would have expected is for spring to fail the test. But it doesn't. It passes happily and I discover the error during deploy to the container.

Why is this so? I see from the docs that it uses a 'SmartContextLoader' and perhaps that defaults to having the Annotation support enabled by default. But it shouldn't really.
Am I missing something? How can I make this test failfast?

Comment: good read [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/)

Comment: hmm, you don't need test this, because annotation `@Autowired` has a property `required`, it is by default `true`, so if it failed to autowire, you will not be able to load application context

Comment: @Jaiwo99 The `required` will kick in only if the `@Autowired` annotation is interpreted which it didnt in my case because I forgot to enable annotations in the applicationcontext.xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-annotations-standard) is the relevant piece of documentation that explains this behavior you see. Quote below:

> The following annotations are supported with standard semantics for all configurations of the Spring TestContext Framework. Note that these annotations are not specific to tests and can be used anywhere in the Spring Framework.

```
* @Autowired
* @Qualifier
* @Resource (javax.annotation) if JSR-250 is present
* @Inject (javax.inject) if JSR-330 is present
* @Named (javax.inject) if JSR-330 is present
* @PersistenceContext (javax.persistence) if JPA is present
* @PersistenceUnit (javax.persistence) if JPA is present
* @Required
* @Transactional
```

And actually in the source code, after digging up a bit: `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` creates a `TestContextManager`, which in turn defines a list of `TestExecutionListener`s. Among the list of default listeners there is one - `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` - which in its `injectDependencies` method will use an `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` to autowire the properties for the test instance. Relevant piece of code is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/support/DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java#L107).

Comment: Well perhaps I phrased my question badly. I was questioning the design of this. If you're writing a test and since the test involves autowiring it can be argued that its an integration test and not a unit test, one would expect it to fail if anything related to the autowiring fails. In effect, I am testing my spring configuration.  I would therefore be surprised if the test passed and the code failed during deployment. I would want the test to fail as an early warning that I missed something.